# Difference between CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE and _start

Tags: kernel, arm, u-boot

I have an *armv7* board and I am seeing a discrepancy.

In my board file I have defined:

```
#define CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE 0x67000004
```

After I build the **u-boot** binary, I ran

```
nm u-boot | grep -w _start
```

It returned the following:

> 67000020 T _start

Would anyone know why there is a difference in the values of `_start`
and `CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE`? I thought they were the same, please
correct me if wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The relevant source is [start.S](http://git.denx.de/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=u-boot.git;a=blob;f=arch/arm/cpu/armv7/start.S) and [u-boot.lds linker](http://git.denx.de/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=u-boot.git;a=blob;f=arch/arm/cpu/u-boot.lds) script.  Assuming that `CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE` is passed as the start address to the linker, there are various segments that can come before.  For instance, many *Rom loaders* need a header to describe or authenticate an image.<sup>Ref1</sup>  This may come before the `_start` symbol (or after).

> I thought they were the same, please correct me if wrong.

You are wrong.  They are not **always** the same.  Given a particular **SOC** and **u-boot** version, they *could be* the same.

**Ref1:** This would be the section `.__image_copy_start` in the referenced linker script.

Comment: But how does _start get assigned a value so close to CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE ?  I have searched through the source code, but not found where _start gets assigned a value..

Comment: I have basically run into a problem, similar to this. But this thread went cold, without giving any useful reason:     u-boot.10912.n7.nabble.com/U-Boot-ARM-gap-between-start-and-CONFIG-SYS-TEXT-BASE-td4134.html

Comment: It depends on the linker script via your **u-boot** version.  Which one are you using. The one from git and which platform exactly?

Comment: I think I am using the default linker script under ./arch/arm/cpu/uboot.lds. Is there a way to verify this for sure from the build ? This is a proprietary platform which hasn't been upstreamed as yet. Also, do you have any thoughts on the issue under the following link:   u-boot.10912.n7.nabble.com/U-Boot-ARM-gap-between-start-and-CONFIG-SYS-TEXT-BASE‌​-td4134.html

Comment: Look at u-boot.map in the main directory.  What is the text around `.text`; or maybe post a *pastebin* of your map file.